# imback functionaliy not returning value to the bot

Tags: json, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I am trying to show some adaptive card buttons when loading the bot.
It is displaying title in the bot. When clicking on title it is returning null to the bot. I want to submit value mentioned in msteams to be submitted.

Code:

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Click me for imBack",
  "data": {
    "msteams": {
      "type": "imBack",
      "value": "Text to reply in chat"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say it's returning null to the bot, do you mean the activity's `text` property is null or its `value` property is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My new blog post may clear up some things about how to use Adaptive Cards with the Bot Framework: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Of particular interest should be the Submit Actions section. You can see that your submit action's data has to be a string in order to trigger the `imBack` behavior. Your action could look like this:

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Click me for imBack",
  "data": "Text to reply in chat"
}
```

This will only work if you don't have any input fields in your card. If you want to have both input fields and `imBack` submit actions, use multiple cards.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to add action **ID** and **title**, see the following:

```
"selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "id": "0",
                "title": "action0",
                "data": {
                    "DataParam": " DataValue"
                }
            }
```

In addition when related actions and card elements does not contain **ID** Teams mobile client will ignore those cards and won't display them at all.

Comment: I have added ID but still same behavior. {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Click me for imBack",
      "id": "1",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "imBack",
          "value": "Text to reply in chat"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Where are you seeing that a submit action object has an ID property? https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html